start a docker-compose inside kuberntes pod
I want to start a docker compose with the cmd docker compose up inside a kubernetes pod
This is my deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-system
  labels:
    app: test
    name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:  
      # init-container 
      initContainers:
      - name: init-docker-compose
        image: k8s-testsystem-init:origin-main-stable
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
          runAsGroup: 0
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args: ["cp -R /opt/docker /data && chmod -R 777 /data/docker && cat /tmp/.env >> /data/docker/.env"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: compose-files
            mountPath: /data
          - name: docker-config
            mountPath: /tmp
      containers:
      # docker 
      - name: docker-test
        image: docker:latest
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args: ["cd /data/docker && docker commpose up"]
        securityContext:
           privileged: true
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
        - containerPort: 5005
        - containerPort: 502
        volumeMounts:
          - name: compose-files
            mountPath: /data
      # volumes
      volumes:
        # modbus profiles volumes
        - name: compose-files
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: docker-config
          configMap: 
            name: docker-configmap
            items: 
              - key: env
                path: .env

If I create this resource the pod exits with:
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

If I remove the cmd and start it via shell everythin works fine.
How can I fix this?

Kubernetes containers don't have access to the Docker socket, if the cluster is even running Docker.  You need to restructure this to use some other technology, possibly the native Kubernetes API.  If possible, I'd avoid dynamically launching containers, since there are a lot of complications around this.

As I mentioned in my post the Pod has access to the docker socket because it runs privileged.  I can not avoid doing this, and this is only a temporaly solution.
The question is how can I start this when the pod starts.

you should look for keyword "DinD" and "DooD"
but I don't recommend both way.
you should make several seperated pods with each docker component

I don't like this way either. First I don't want to run the pod priviliged and second the way DinD is used. Open the TCP Socket  is also a bad idea.
The problem is that there are 3 container which must be in the same network with different IPs. One can not be called via DNS and the other only reacts only on multicast with a TTL 1.  Its horrible

I also agree starting pod as priviliged. you might make you containers as sidecar, but still your previous docker-compose container uses seperate ports, and you can controll internal / external ports with various functions.
